# How to fix SBT 0.11 not finding the main class of my application?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've created an SBT 0.11 project of an only one source code file (yet):

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```

When try to `run` the application with SBT, I get "java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected".

How do I define the main class?

I have used "full configuration" with the folowing `Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._

object MyBuild extends Build {
  lazy val HelloWorld = Project("HelloWorld ", file("src"))
}
```

And the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "HelloWorld"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"
```

Comment: can you check using `Application` instead? Or defining your own `main` method? I'm not telling you to do this on prod but just to check if your class is being picked by sbt

Comment: @pablo-fernandez tried both, neither helps.

Comment: What's your directory structure? I'm not trusting the `file("src")` part

Comment: @pablo-fernandez The code file is `\HelloWorld\src\main\scala\HelloWorld.scala`, the config is `\HelloWorld\project\Build.scala`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
lazy val HelloWorld = Project("HelloWorld ", file("src"))
```

with:

```
lazy val HelloWorld = Project("HelloWorld ", file("."))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Project`'s second parameter indicate what is the base directory of that project, which assumes you have many projects. If the path to your source code was `HelloWorld\src\src\main\scala\HelloWorld.scala`, then that original line would work.

The thing is... that second parameter does *not* point to the source code. It points to the project. For example, you'd see it probably created the directory `HelloWorld\src\target` at the time you tried to use the original configuration.